# Values of the zeta function of a modular form at negative integers

Tags: number-theory

Suppose $f$ is an eigenform of level $N$ and weight $k$. Then, we can define a zeta function $L(s,f)$ attached to $f$. There are lots of studies about the values of $L(s,f)$ at integers between 1 and $k-1$. However, I have not been able to find out some references about the values of $L(s,f)$ outside this range. I am particularly interested in the values of $L(s,f)$ at negative integers.

There is only one case that I am quite familiar with. That is when $f$ corresponds to a CM elliptic curve. In this case, $L(-n,f)=0$ so it is not very interesting.

So my question is: what do we know about $L(-n,f)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those things are in Diamond and Shurman.

If $f\in S_k(\Gamma_1(N))$,

$L(s,f)$ is the Dirichlet series $\sum_n a_n(f)n^{-s}$, from the easy bound $|a_n(f)|=O(n^{k/2})$ it converges at least for $\Re(s)> k/2+1$ and $$(2\pi)^{-s} \Gamma(s) L(s,f)=\mathcal{M}[f(iy)](s)$$ Due to the exponential decay at the cusps $\mathcal{M}[f(iy)](s)$ is entire so that the analytic continuation of $L(s,f)$ is entire and has a zero at each pole of $\Gamma(s)$.

Also (Fricke involution)  $$\pmatrix{0&1\\-N&0}^{-1}\pmatrix{1+Na&b\\Nc&1+Nd}\pmatrix{0&1\\-N&0}=\pmatrix{1+Nd&b\\Nc&1+Na}$$
gives that $$f(z)=(Nz)^{-k} f^*(-1/(Nz))$$ where $f^*$ is again in $S_k(\Gamma_1(N))$, which gives the functional equation $$(2\pi)^{-s} \Gamma(s) L(s,f)=\mathcal{M}[f(iy)](s)$$ $$=\mathcal{M}[(iyN)^{-k} f^*(i/(Ny))](s)=(iN)^{-k}N^{k-s}\mathcal{M}[f^*(iy)](k-s)$$

Comment: Thanks! It is a very nice and elegant answer (that could generalize to the L-function of a pure motive).

Comment: Sorry I changed my answer many times, we don't need the functional equation, only that for a cusp form $f(iy) = O(e^{-2\pi y})$ at $\infty$ and $=O( y^{-k} e^{-2\pi /y})$ at $0$, so that $\mathcal{M}[f(iy)](s)$ is entire. It remains to check when $f$ doesn't vanish at the cusps in which case $\mathcal{M}[f(iy)](s)$ has two poles at $0,k$ and $L(-n,f)=0$ for $n>0$. Finally $L(0,f)$ can be found from substracting an Eisenstein series to get a cusp form.

Comment: The L-functions of Eisenstein series are linear combination of $L(s,\chi)L(s,\chi')$ for some Dirichlet characters and $L(0,\chi)$ is the mean value of $\sum_{n\le N} \chi(n)$

Comment: Thanks again! Regardings $L(0, \chi)$, you probably meant, it is the mean value of $\sum_{n} \chi(n)n$.

Comment: For $\chi$ non-principal $L(0,\chi) = \lim_{s\to 0}L(s,\chi)= \lim_{s\to 0} s \int_1^\infty (\sum_{n\le x}\chi(n)) x^{-s-1}dx$ and $\int_1^\infty (-A+\sum_{n\le x}\chi(n)) x^{-1}dx$ converges where $A=\sum_{n=1}^q \chi(n) \frac{q-n}q$ is the mean value of the $q$-periodic function $\sum_{n\le x}\chi(n)$ so $L(0,\chi) = A$

Comment: Very nice! Thanks!